# imagejpeg() Issue with unicode characters

Tags: php, image-processing

I use `imagejpeg()` to save a resized image to a file, The file name can contain non latin characters, The issue is that it messes up the file name with some weird characters.

Any idea how to fix this? If not how to return the content of `imagejpeg()` instead of saving it or printing it so i can use `fwrite()` instead?

*P.S. The same thing happens with `imagepng()` and `imagegif()` too.*

Comment: Any specific reason you need those non-latin characters in the file name?

Answer (score 1):

Although I would recommend not using non-latin characters in filenames, you can use output buffering to capture the output of `imagejpeg` and store it in a variable. If `fwrite` does accept your filename, you can use it to write your variable to a file.

Something like:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($your_image);
$your_image_variable = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```